# ucfr: Attempt from package php5-cli to take /etc/php5/cli/php.ini away from package libapache2-mod-php

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, dpkg

Дистрибутив: Ubuntu 14.04

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install 
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
обновлено 0, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 22 пакетов не обновлено.
не установлено до конца или удалено 4 пакетов.
После данной операции, объём занятого дискового пространства возрастёт на 0 B.
Настраивается пакет php5-cli (5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.18) …
ucfr: Attempt from package php5-cli  to take /etc/php5/cli/php.ini away from package libapache2-mod-php5
ucfr: Aborting.
dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета php5-cli (--configure):
 подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 4
dpkg: зависимости пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет php5-readline:
 php5-readline зависит от php5-cli (= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.18), однако:
  Пакет php5-cli пока не настроен.

dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета php5-readline (--configure):
 проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным
dpkg: зависимости пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет php-pear:
 php-pear зависит от php5-cli, однако:
  Пакет php5-cli пока не настроен.

dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета php-pear (--configure):
 проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным
dpkg: зависимости пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет pkg-php-tools:
 pkg-php-tools зависит от php5-cli, однако:
  ПакеОтчёты apport не записаны, так как сообщение об ошибке указывает на повторную ошибку от предыдущего отказа.
                                 Отчёты apport не записаны, так как сообщение об ошибке указывает на повторную ошибку от предыдущего отказа.
                                                            Отчёты apport не записаны, так достигнут MaxReports
                               т php5-cli пока не настроен.
 pkg-php-tools зависит от php-pear, однако:
  Пакет php-pear пока не настроен.

dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета pkg-php-tools (--configure):
 проблемы  зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 php5-cli
 php5-readline
 php-pear
 pkg-php-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Как исправить эти ошибки?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/185979/110559

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ucfr: Attempt from package php5-cli  to take /etc/php5/cli/php.ini away from package libapache2-mod-php5

вероятно, `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` в вашей системе — это символическая ссылка, указывающая на файл, принадлежащий пакету `libapache2-mod-php5`.

уточнить можно, например, так:

```
$ ls -l /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

---

удалите или, для надёжности, переименуйте эту символическую ссылку `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`, и повторите ту же команду. ни одна из перечисленных в приведённом логе ошибок уже не должна появиться.

---

аналогичный вопрос на другом сайте: [Can't finish php5-cli update](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/185802/110559)

Answer (score 0):

Разработчик `deb.sury.org` Ondřej Surý не хочет это исправлять:

> You most likely symlinked the php.ini between the packages. That’s not supported.

[github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/1473#issuecomment-713839096](https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/1473#issuecomment-713839096)

Поэтому я исправил это сам правками файлов `deb.sury.org` в папке `/var/lib/dpkg/info/`.
Я описал своё решение для **PHP 7.4**: [df.tips/t/1940/3](https://df.tips/t/1940/3)
Для других версий PHP решение аналогично.